# Equivalent Component for outputPanel in core jsf

Tags: java, jsf

I am facing a situation where i have to use a component wrapper, or something that does the same as "outputPanel"  in primefaces. do you know any ?

Comment: What specific functionality from `outputPanel` do you need?

Comment: @partlov I needed to rerender DataTable from an ajax action fired from a command link inside it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you asked for an equivalent component wrapper, I would suggest using panelGrid with columns value of one.

```
<h:panelGrid id="grid" columns="1">
</h:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 2):

> *I needed to rerender DataTable from an ajax action fired from a command link inside it*

Just reference the data table itself.

```html
<h:form id="form">
    <h:dataTable id="table" ...>
        <h:column>
            <h:commandLink ...>
                <f:ajax ... render=":form:table" />
            </h:commandLink>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Or, if you really insist for some unclear reason, the plain JSF equivalent of `<p:outputPanel>` is just `<h:panelGroup>`.

```html
<h:form id="form">
    <h:panelGroup id="group">
        <h:dataTable ...>
            <h:column>
                <h:commandLink ...>
                    <f:ajax ... render=":form:group" />
                </h:commandLink>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```